# Autofilled State & Zip code in Magento

Tags: magento, zip, state, checkout, autofill

Our website has recently started autofilling the state and zip code on the Magento checkout page. It is always filled in for Utah, and so we know it is not a caching issue. I'm not really sure what I can do at this point, as I have already attempted emptying the site cache on the magento backend.

Here is the website if anyone has ideas on how to resolve this.

https://store.liquidaminodiet.com

Comment: Is it doing it for everyone, or just you? You can try clearing your browser cookies/browse incognito to get rid of your session.

Comment: Did you have this problem before installing the plugin or after? have you try disabling the onepagecheckout.xml file on modules to see if the problem shows as well in the default checkout?

Comment: It is doing this for all of the customers. How would I disable the onepagecheckout.xml? This is a recent problem, and we have had this feature for a long time.